# How to display images from the database using prepared statments in PHP?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I am building a blog application where in a user can post blogs and upload images. And one of the features of the blog is to display the profile image of the current user in the database in the header. I am using procedural style of PHP and prepared statements in order to display the image but what I get is a broken image link instead of the image itself.
Here is my code in the fetching of images using SELECT statements and prepared statements:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT user_image FROM users WHERE user_name = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $profile_picture);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $profile_picture);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    $profile_picture = $stmt['user_image'];
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
 ?>
```

And here is the code where in I am displaying the image of the user that is being selected in the database:

```
<img width='30' class='img-responsive; img-circle' src='../images/<?php echo $profile_picture; ?>'>
```

My question is how can I be able to correctly display the images in the database using prepared statements using procedural style PHP? I am quite new in using prepared statements and having some few setbacks in it. I understand and know how to use prepared statements using INSERT statements but I am having trouble using it in SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $profile_picture);
you should replace the variable $profile_picture with $username

Comment: you can also init the $profile_picture variable to a default picture in case nothing returns from the DB

Comment: Thanks. I got that to work. Silly mistake of mine, not noticing it before posting the question. Thanks again, @guy ribak...